# Why is 900MHz restricted in some areas in the US?

Tags: united-states, legal, 33cm-band

So I found these rules:

> (2)
>   No
>   amateur
>   station
>   shall
>   transmit
>   from
>   those
>   portions
>   of
>   Texas
>   and
>   New
>   Mexico
>   that
>   are
>   bounded
>   by
>   latitudes
>   31°41
>   ′
>   and
>   34°30
>   ′
>   North
>   and
>   longitudes
>   104°11
>   ′
>   and
>   107°30
>   ′
>   West;
>   or
>   from
>   outside
>   of
>   the
>   United
>   States
>   and
>   its
>   Region
>   2
>   insular
>   areas.
>
> (3)
>   No
>   amateur
>   station
>   shall
>   transmit
>   from
>   those
>   portions
>   of
>   Colorado
>   and
>   Wyoming
>   that
>   are
>   bounded
>   by
>   latitudes
>   39° and
>   42° North
>   and
>   longitudes
>   103°
>   and
>   108° West
>   in
>   the
>   following
>   segments:
>   902.4–902.6
>   MHz,
>   904.3–904.7
>   MHz,
>   925.3–925.7
>   MHz,
>   and
>   927.3–927.7
>   MHz.

But I can't find exactly what the government needs 30MHz of bandwidth for, especially in the middle of New Mexico.

What is the reason for this restriction?

Comment: In the rules, note the 'other nations' part of the rule - have you checked what Mexico's allocations in that band are?

Comment: Well why wouldn't they restrict Arizona also then? And this does not explain why Colorado and Wyoming are restricted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New Mexico restriction covers the [White Sands Missile Range](http://www.wsmr.army.mil).  Colorado and Wyoming also have military installations.  Some 900 MHz frequencies are allowed for amateurs there.  More comments at http://www.qsl.net/kb9mwr/projects/900mhz/900users.html

Comment: And you are correct, and my guess in a comment above was incorrect. Living a few hours north of WSMR I should have figured that one out (sigh). Agreements with Mexico are available on the FCC website at https://transition.fcc.gov/ib/sand/agree/mex_frequency.html and those don't show up in the table. KE5UCG

Comment: Honestly we don't need 25MHz. Can't they give New Mexico a few MHz at least? I am in Colorado where they do have restrictions, but I am happy with what they give us.

Comment: @Skyler440 Last I knew, they were still testing EMP devices (among _many_ other classified tests) out there. Keeping out of that whole 25MHz could be as much for our protection as their convenience if their EMPs are operating @ or near that band. I don't know about you, but I'd be seriously upset if I 'caught' one of those pulses while trying to rag-chew on UHF! lol